# Conditionally bundling assets based on flavor

Tags: flutter, dart

```yaml
flutter:

  assets:
    - assets/comum/images/
    - path: assets/premium/images/
      flavors: 
        - premium
    - path: assets/free/images/
      flavors: 
        - free
```

It's giving this error:

**Assets are required to be file paths (strings).
Try converting the value to be a string.**

But I researched a lot of information but none of it worked, even the recent post about it but I did exactly the same but it just gives this error and when emulating the app it gives this error:

**Assent manifest contains a null or empty uri
Assent manifest contains a null or empty uri**

Comment: I don't know anything about flutter, but could it be that you have a typo? In your `path` you have `imagens` instead of `images`

Comment: They are both written in the same way (I will correct them here in the post for images) but they are all written in the same way, there is even a post on the official page about it but it says nothing about adding something more (link: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors#:~:text=Conditionally%20bundling%20assets%20based%20on%20flavor,-If%20you%20aren&text=If%20you%20have%20assets%20that,being%20bloated%20by%20unused%20assets. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is introduced as part of Flutter 3.19.0.  see [Flutter 3.19.0 release notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes/release-notes-3.19.0) issue 132985

Upgrade Flutter SDK to the latest version should fix the issue.

Comment: This helped me I was on version 3.10.4 after changing it to the version you mentioned it worked